# Difference between electric field and electric force

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, terminology

What is the difference between electric *field* and electric *force*? Both seem to do the same thing, but their formulas are different.

Answer (score 2):

The electric field is a function on spacetime, $\vec E:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$, that can be used to calculate the electric force experienced by a charge at a given point. This is given by the equation
$$\vec F = q\vec E(\vec x,t)$$
where $\vec F$ is the electric force on the charge $q$, located at position $\vec x$ at time $t$. The key difference between these two quantities is that electric field is a function of position (and time), whereas the electric force applied by an electric field is associated with a particular object.

Answer (score 1):

Field is force per unit charge. The field tells you what the force would be on a particle with a charge of 1, if such a particle was there. Force is what the actual force is on whatever particle is there. The force that a particle puts on *another* particle of charge of 1, is the same as the field that first particle makes.

But if the second particle has a charge of 100, the first particle’s field will be 1/100th as much as the force it is putting on the second particle. Because the first particle’s field means how much force it’d put on a particle of charge 1, if it was there. (Regardless of what is there).

Answer (score 0):

In essence, an **electric field** $E$ is **electric force $F$ per charge $q$**:

$$E=\frac Fq.$$

We associate any point with an electric field. This is thus the force that *would be applied* to a unit charge, should it be placed there. So,

- the electric field represents what *will* happen and it is always present, where as
- the electric force (any force) represents what *is* happening and is only present where there is something that the force is acting on.